# two way comparison in merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a source table:

```
    create table source_after (
    binary_path varchar2(40),
    hostname varchar2(40),
    change_column varchar2(40),
    flag varchar2(20) default 'open'
    );
    
    insert all 
    into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('java','b','DMZ') 
    into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('apache','c','drn')
    into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('NEW','NEW','NEW')
    select * from dual;

--------
binary_path hostname flag change_column
java         b      open       DMZ
apache       c      open       drn
NEW          NEW    open       NEW
```

And a destination table:

```
create table destination (
binary_path varchar2(40),
hostname varchar2(40),
change_column varchar2(40),
flag varchar2(20) 
);


insert all 
into destination (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('python','a','drn') 
into destination (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('java','b','drn') 
into destination (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('apache','c','drn')
into destination (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('spark','d','drn')
select * from dual;

------
binary_path hostname change_column flag
python      a         drn           null
java        b         drn           null
apache      c         drn           null
spark       d         drn           null
```

The primary key of both tables is the combination `(binary_path,hostname)` . I want to merge into destination the changes of `source_after`.

These should be:

1. If the primary key in `destination` is present in `source_after`, I want to update `change_column` in `destination` with the value of `source_after`.
2. If the primary key in `destination` is not present in `source_after`, I want to mark the `flag` column as `closed`.
3. If the primary key in `source_after` is not present in `destination`, I want to insert the row  present in `source_after` which is not present in `destination`.

I have tried this:

```
merge into destination d
using (select * from source_after) s on (d.hostname = s.hostname and d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
when matched then update
set 
d.change_column = s.change_column,
d.flag = s.flag
when not matched then insert 
(d.binary_path,d.hostname,d.change_column,d.flag)
values
(s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag)
;

binary_path hostname change_column flag
    python  a   drn null
    java    b   DMZ open
    apache  c   drn open
    spark   d   drn null
    NEW    NEW  NEW open
```

It solves problem `1` and `3` , but not problem `2` which is marking  the column `flag` as closed.

Comment: Oracle does not support the `MATCHED BY TARGET`/`MATCHED BY SOURCE` syntax in a `MERGE` statement so you cannot do it in a single statement.

Comment: You can do this, but you'd have to do it by working out the data set in the source query (e.g. do a full outer join between your destination and source_after tables).

Comment: [example dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rILeJ0Du)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in the `USING` clause and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column for the destination between the `USING` clause and the target of the `MERGE`:

```sql
MERGE INTO destination d
USING (
  SELECT d.ROWID AS rid,
         s.*
  FROM   destination d
         FULL OUTER JOIN source_after s
         ON (d.hostname = s.hostname AND d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
) s
ON (s.rid = d.ROWID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET d.change_column = COALESCE(s.change_column, d.change_column),
        d.flag          = COALESCE(s.flag, 'closed')
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (d.binary_path,d.hostname,d.change_column,d.flag)
    VALUES (s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag);
```

Which, for the sample data, changes the `destination` table to:

| BINARY_PATH | HOSTNAME | CHANGE_COLUMN | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | a | drn | closed |
| java | b | DMZ | open |
| apache | c | drn | open |
| spark | d | drn | closed |
| NEW | NEW | NEW | open |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gEWxweCX)

Comment: this is neat. I need to digest the pseudo-column trick. Did not understand

Comment: @moth `ROWID` is effectively a pointer directly to the row and by correlating on it the SQL engine does not need to search the `destination` table for the row twice as you know exactly where the row is from the first time the table is queried.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, that won't work - not in a single statement.

- If *something* MATCHES, you can UPDATE it
- If there's NO MATCH, you can INSERT it
- You can't combine NO MATCH with UPDATE, which means that you'll have to write two statements

Comment: You can do it by changing your source: (https://dbfiddle.uk/eZkofVur)
using (
 select s.binary_path, s.hostname, s.change_column, s.flag from source_after s
 union all
 select d.binary_path, d.hostname, d.change_column, 'closed' from destination d
 where not exists(select 1 from source_after s where s.binary_path = d.binary_path and s.hostname = d.hostname)
) s 
Result: 

python a drn closed

java b DMZ open

apache c drn open

spark d drn closed

NEW NEW NEW open

Comment: The result is exactly the same as the original merge followed by a separate update to match condition 2: 5 rows where python and spark are flagged as 'closed' instead of null in the original merge.

Answer (score 1):

```
merge into destination d
using (
    select s.binary_path, s.hostname, s.change_column, s.flag from source_after s
    union all
    select d.binary_path, d.hostname, d.change_column, 'closed' from destination d
    where not exists(select 1 from source_after s where s.binary_path = d.binary_path and s.hostname = d.hostname)
) s 
on (d.hostname = s.hostname and d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
when matched then update
set 
    d.change_column = s.change_column, 
    d.flag = s.flag
when not matched then insert 
(d.binary_path,d.hostname,d.change_column,d.flag)
values
(s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag)
;
```